# delay loading of a background image using id:hover css3 or html5

Tags: css, html

I would like to delay the loading of an image on :hover for 1 second every time it is moused over.

Is this possible?

code is:

```
<style>
#bg {background-image: url(bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position:absolute;  
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;display: block;
height: 354px;width: 571px;
border: 1px solid #000000; }
#delay {position: absolute;  
width: 100%;  
height: 354px;  
}
#delay:hover {background: transparent url(delay.png) no-repeat;}  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg"> </div>
<div id="delay"> </div>
```

Comment: You could probably do it with CSS3, definitely jQuery. My question to you is why?

Comment: use java script for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using CSS transitions, change the opacity from 0 to 1, in zero seconds, with a one second delay:

```
#delay {
    background: transparent url(delay.jpg) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0s linear;
   -o-transition: opacity 0s linear;
}
#delay:hover {
   -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
   -o-transition-delay: 1s;
   opacity: 1
}
```

Currently only supported in Chrome/Safari/Opera

Answer (score 0):

You should pre load background image on the page.

```
.hover:before {
  content: url("/hover-image-path.jpg");
  width:0;
  height:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```